# how to use openapi with labelSelector?

Tags: kubernetes, openapi, kubectl

I want to use OpenAPI to get and filter pod, but labelSelector is not working. There is no result.

[image]

```
curl -k -H "Authorization: Bearer ${my_token}" --silent  https://192.168.35.60:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods?labelSelector=app%3Dactivemq&limit=500
```

[image]

```
kubectl get pod -l app=activemq --v 8
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.